# Difference in URL Routing?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, url-routing

Is there a difference between the url rewriting in the web config and using the url routing within the global.asax?

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Category", "categories/{name}", "~/ShowPostsByCategory.aspx");
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("BlogPost", "posts/{year}/{month}/{day}/{id}", "~/ShowPost.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL Rewriting is handled at the IIS level and directs the request at the web server level.  ASP.NET Routing handles directing a request to the appropriate handler at the Application level.  Look at the link below for more details.

[IIS URL Rewriting verses ASP.NET Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/496/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing/)